# Formatting with method TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

actually my code is perfectly working. Code is actually creating a temporary query in Access for each supplier, i have in a table. After creating the query, next step is, saving the query as a Excel - file in my submitted path. After that, my code is creating a mail with an PDF as Attachement and with the Excel file as attachement for each supplier.

But is there a possibility to formatting after or into TransferSpreadsheet - method the columns widthness after saving the Excel - file? It would be also nice if first row has a bond. Here's my code

```
    Sub ExcelExportuSenden()

     Dim day As Integer
     day = Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
     Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
     Dim toMulti, waarde As String
     Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem ' An Outlook Mail item
     Dim dbs As Database
     Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
     Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
     Dim originalSql As String
     Dim Identified_name As Recordset
     Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
     Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
     Dim rs  As Recordset
     Dim filename As String

     filename = Me.txt_path_pdf_description

     Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Mail")  'Get name for the&amp;nbsp;email recipient

     If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
         rs.MoveFirst
         Do Until rs.EOF
              With mItem
                 Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                 toMulti = rs![eMail]
                 waarde = toMulti
                 For Each qdf In dbs.QueryDefs
                     If qdf.Name = "inquiry" & "_" & rs!supplier Then
                       dbs.QueryDefs.Delete "inquiry" & "_" & rs!supplier 
                       Exit For

                     End If
                 Next

                 Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("inquiry" & "_" & rs!supplier) '
                 With dbs
                      qdfTemp.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Filter_inquiry_original] WHERE [supplier] = '" & rs![supplier] & "'"
                      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "inquiry" & "_" & rs!supplier, Me.txt_path & "\inquiry" & "_" & rs!supplier & ".xlsx", True
                      DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "inquiry" & "_" & rs!Lsupllier
                 End With

         .To = toMulti
'          MsgBox toMulti
         .Subject = "Anfrage zur Ausschreibung" & "_" & rs!Lieferant
         .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,<br><br>" & _
         "anbei erhalten Sie eine Ausschreibung, mit der Bitte um Bearbeitung!"
         .Display
'          .Send
         .Attachments.Add filename
         .Attachments.Add (Me.txt_path & "\inquiry" & "_" & rs!supplier & ".xlsx")


     End With

        rs.MoveNext
     Loop
 Else
     MsgBox "No email address!"
 End If
 olApp.Quit
 Set olApp = Nothing
 Exit Sub



 End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You code can't do that. Before adding it as an attachment, you would have to open Excel and the workbook via automation and run code to apply the format and other settings. Then save and continue.

Comment: Gustav is right. I prefer to do the entire export using automation, and export the table/query using `.CopyFromRecordset`. That way I don't have to create a file, and then open it and modify it, but I can do both in one go, and I don't even need to create a temporary query.

Comment: There is definitely VBA code that you can use to open your excel sheet and format it, but you probably don't have to do that. You can use an empty pre-formatted template. Copy it and transfer your data on it and it should retain the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. Here my code:

```
 Sub ExcelExportuSenden3()

 Dim day As Integer
 day = Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim toMulti, waarde As String
 Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem ' An Outlook Mail item
 Dim dbs As Database
 Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
 Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
 Dim originalSql As String
 Dim Identified_name As Recordset
 Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
 Set dbs = CurrentDb
 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Dim rs  As Recordset
 Dim filename As String
' Dim filename3 As String
 Dim xlApp As Object, xlWB As Object, xlsheet As Object
 Dim TabNam As String
 TabNam = "Tabelle1"

 filename = Me.txt_Pfad_mitKunde

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Mailversand")  'Get name for the&amp;nbsp;email recipient

        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
           rs.MoveFirst

                Do Until rs.EOF
                    With mItem
                        Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                                    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                                    toMulti = rs![eMail]
                                    waarde = toMulti
        For Each qdf In dbs.QueryDefs

                 If qdf.Name = "Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant Then
                    dbs.QueryDefs.Delete "Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant
                    Exit For
                 End If

        Next

             Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef("Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant) '
                With dbs
                  qdfTemp.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [_Anfragematrix] WHERE [Lieferant] = '" & rs![Lieferant] & "'"
                  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant, Me.txt_Speicherpfad & "\Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant & ".xlsx", True _
                                                    , TabNam

                  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                  xlApp.Visible = True
                  Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Me.txt_Speicherpfad & "\Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant & ".xlsx")
                  Set xlsheet = xlWB.Sheets(TabNam)

                        With xlsheet
                            .Columns.AutoFit

                            With .Range("A1:O1")

                                With .Interior
                                    .ColorIndex = 15
                                    .Pattern = xlSolid

                                End With

                            End With

                        End With

                    xlWB.Save
                    xlWB.Close True
                    Set xlWB = Nothing
                    xlApp.Quit
                    Set xlApp = Nothing

                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant

                 End With

         .To = toMulti
'          MsgBox toMulti
         .Subject = "Anfrage zur Ausschreibung" & "_" & rs!Lieferant
         .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,<br><br>" & _
         "anbei erhalten Sie eine Ausschreibung, mit der Bitte um Bearbeitung!"
         .Display
'         .Send
         .Attachments.Add filename
         .Attachments.Add (Me.txt_Speicherpfad & "\Anfrage" & "_" & rs!Lieferant & ".xlsx")


     End With

        rs.MoveNext
     Loop
 Else
     MsgBox "No email address!"
 End If
 olApp.Quit
 Set olApp = Nothing
 Exit Sub



 End Sub
```